# How to set Type field using YoutrackSharp

Tags: c#, youtrack, youtracksharp

I am trying to create a new issue in youtrack from a C# application. Everything works fine so far, except that the Type field is not set correctly.

I tried setting the Type as an integer (since the field is actually an enum field) as well as as a string. Neither yields the correct type in the issue, but it always shows the default type.

Using a **string**

```cs
var issue =  new Issue
            {
                Summary = "Summary",
                Description = "Description"             
            };
issue.SetField("Type", "Exception");
```

Using an **integer** (enum access)

```cs
var issue =  new Issue
            {
                Summary = "Summary",
                Description = "Description"             
            };
issue.SetField("Type", 0);
```

I would expect that the issue get the type "Exception" but is always stays at the default ("Task" in this case)

EDIT:
So it turns out the SetField command works fine. The reason it did not work was due to a restriction in YouTrack itself which required "Exception" issues to have a second field "How to reproduce" filled out. The command by itself actually throws an exception (which got caught by the calling code)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you used issue ID instead of project short name in first parameter of service.CreateIssue(). Please look through this example:

```
    var service = connection.CreateIssuesService();

    var newIssue = new Issue
    {
        Summary = "Test issue",
        Description = "Test issue description."
    };

    newIssue.SetField("Assignee", "root");
    newIssue.SetField("Type", "Bug"); // non default value
    newIssue.SetField("Due Date", DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(5));

    var result = service.CreateIssue("SP", newIssue).Result;
```

Comment: Hi Daria Vasina, thank you for your reply. I actually found the source of the problem and forgot to update the question. The project was set up to require a second field to be filled out in Exception issues. 
This lead to an exception which was caught silently by the calling code.
I checked out the source code of YoutrackSharp and found that it just calls commands on the issue to set fields. This, unfortunately, does not allow to set multiple fields in one go so I was forced to deactivate the requirement for the second field. But now it works.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Maybe you can set this second field before setting Type? Or this second field is conditional and appears only for Exceptions?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this field is conditional. For now I deactivated the requirement to provide a value.

Comment: I didn't try it with YouTrack Sharp but as I can see in IssuesService code you can try to use ApplyCommand with "type Exception SecondField SecondValue" as command parameter to set up several fields.